# If graph has at least $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor +1$ edges, then some edge appears in at least $(1/6-o(1))n$ triangles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

> Prove that every $n$-vertex graph with at least $\lfloor
>  n^2/4\rfloor+1$ edges contains some edge in at least $(1/6-o(1))n$
> triangles, and that this constant $1/6$ is best possible.

I have been thinking on this problem for a while and the following idea came to my mind. It is basically averaging argument since we need to show an existence of some edge which appears in $(1/6-o(1))n$ triangles.

**My attempt:** For any edge $uv\in E(G)$ consider the following set $N(u)\cap N(v)=\{x\in V(G): xu,xv\in E(G)\}$, i.e. this set represents all triangles where $uv$ is one of the sides. Let's apply averaging argument on the size of $N(u)\cap N(v)$, i.e. consider the sum
$$\sum \limits_{uv\in E(G)}|N(u)\cap N(v)|=\sum \limits_{uv\in E(G)}|\{x\in V(G): xu,xv\in E(G)\}|=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}|\{(u,v,x)\in V^3: uv,xu,xv\in E(G)\}|=3|\Delta_G|,$$
where $|\Delta_G|$ is the number of triangles in graph $G$. Here I am using the non-trivial fact that if $e(G)\geq \lfloor n^2/4\rfloor+1$, then $|\Delta_G|\geq \lfloor
 n/2\rfloor$.
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{e(G)}\sum \limits_{uv\in E(G)}|N(u)\cap N(v)|\geq \frac{3|\Delta_G|}{e(G)}\geq \frac{3\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{e(G)}.$$

Hence there is an edge $uv\in E(G)$ such that $|N(u)\cap N(v)|\geq \frac{3\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{e(G)}$. But of course it does not give the desired result.

I was wondering is it possible to modify this method to solve the problem?

Comment: We can rephrase your argument without the sums: since a graph with $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor+1$ edges has at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ triangles, and each triangle has $3$ edges, the number of triangles on the average edge is $\frac{3 \cdot \lfloor n/2\rfloor}{e(G)}$. We can't improve the bound for the number of triangles on the *average* edge, since this is exactly what we see if we take $K_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \lceil n/2\rceil}$ and add an edge inside the larger part. A solution to this problem must somehow locate the correct edge inside such a graph, which is in unusually many triangles.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I agree with you! This is what I also had in my mind. I was wondering do you know the solution of this problem? If yes, can you upload it please? I'd highly appreciate this!

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I found the proof of this problem among one of the papers of Erdos and posted it as answer. I think that Erdos paper has some typoes\small mistakes so I've tried to fix them. However, there is only one question in his proof which I cannot understand. I was wondering can you help me to understand it, please?

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem as a Lemma 2 in a paper of Paul Erdos ["On a theorem of Rademacher-Turan".](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1962-09.pdf)

**Remark:** I am gonna write the proof in my own words with more details. However, there was one moment in the proof which I did not understand at all so I'd be very grateful if someone can explain it to me.

> **Statement.** If $G$ is a graph on $n$ vertices and $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor+1$ edges, then there is an edge which appears in at least
> $\lfloor n/6\rfloor$ triangles.

*Proof.* Let $\{\{\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1\},\dots,\{\alpha_r,\beta_r,\gamma_r\}\}$ be a maximal system of disjoint triangles in our graph $G$. In other words, if we remove there $3r$ vertices, we obtain a triangle-free graph on $n-3r$ vertices and by Turan's theorem it has at most $\lfloor (n-3r)^2/4\rfloor$ edges.

Denote by $G(n,i)$ the graph $G-\sum \limits_{j=1}^{i-1}(\alpha_j+\beta_j+\gamma_j)$, i.e.  we removed the vertices $\{\alpha_j,\beta_j,\gamma_j\}$ for $1\leq j\leq i-1$ from original graph $G$. Let $v^{(i)}(\alpha_i), v^{(i)}(\beta_i), v^{(i)}(\gamma_i)$ are the degrees of $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i$ in $G(n,i)$.

We claim that for some $i\in \{1,\dots,r\}$ we should have $v^{(i)}(\alpha_i)+v^{(i)}(\beta_i)+v^{(i)}(\gamma_i)>\dfrac{5n}{2}-3i$. In the original proof of Erdos I just took $c_2=1/6$. If this is not true, then for any $i\in \{1,\dots,r\}$ we have $v^{(i)}(\alpha_i)+v^{(i)}(\beta_i)+v^{(i)}(\gamma_i)\leq \dfrac{5n}{2}-3i$. Since,

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{r}\left(v^{(i)}(\alpha_i)+v^{(i)}(\beta_i)+v^{(i)}(\gamma_i)\right)+3r\leq \left\lfloor \frac{(n-3r)^2}{4}\right\rfloor \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1\leq\sum \limits_{i=1}^{r}\left(v^{(i)}(\alpha_i)+v^{(i)}(\beta_i)+v^{(i)}(\gamma_i)\right)-3r+ \left\lfloor \frac{(n-3r)^2}{4}\right\rfloor.$$
hence $$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1\leq\sum \limits_{i=1}^{r}\left(\frac{5n}{2}-3i\right)-3r+ \left\lfloor \frac{(n-3r)^2}{4}\right\rfloor.$$
However, one can show that $$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{r}\left(\frac{5n}{2}-3i\right)-3r+ \left\lfloor \frac{(n-3r)^2}{4}\right\rfloor\leq \left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor,$$
which gives a contradiction.

Hence there is $i_0\in \{1,\dots,r\}$ such that $v^{(i_0)}(\alpha_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\beta_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\gamma_{i_0})>\dfrac{5n}{2}-3i_0.$ Then a simple computation shows that there are at least $3\lfloor n/6\rfloor$ vertices of $G(n,i_0)$ which are connected with more than one of the vertices of $\{\alpha_{i_0},\beta_{i_0},\gamma_{i_0}\}$. Therefore there are at least $\lfloor n/6 \rfloor$ of them which are connected with the same pair, i.e. $G(n,i_0)$, and therefore original graph $G$ contains an edge which appears in at least $\lfloor n/6\rfloor$ triangles. This is the proof of the statement.

**Question.** But I have one question which bothers me. Can anyone explain why are there at least $3\lfloor n/6\rfloor$ vertices of $G(n,i_0)$ which are connected with more than one of the vertices of $\{\alpha_{i_0},\beta_{i_0},\gamma_{i_0}\}$? I don't see any simple computation here as Erdos claims.

Comment: Think about adding edges between $\{\alpha_{i_0}, \beta_{i_0}, \gamma_{i_0}\}$ and the other $n-3i_0$ vertices in $G(n,i_0)$ one at a time. Such an edge either connects a new vertex to $\{\alpha_{i_0}, \beta_{i_0}, \gamma_{i_0}\}$, or creates at least one triangle. The first thing can only happen at most $n-3i_0$ times, thus at least $(\frac52n-3i_0)-(n-3i_0)=\frac12n$ triangles are created. The triangles all contain one of the three edges $\{\alpha_{i_0}\beta_{i_0},\alpha_{i_0}\gamma_{i_0},\beta_{i_0}\gamma_{i_0}\}$, so one of the three edges gets at least $\frac16n$ of the triangles.

Comment: This is the part I understand. I didn't post Erdos's proof because I don't understand one other part. Why do you say that $$\sum_{i=1}^r \left(\frac{5n}{2}-3i\right)-3r+ \left\lfloor \frac{(n-3r)^2}{4}\right\rfloor\leq \left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor?$$In particular, if $r$ is close to $n/3$, the sum for $i=1,\dots,r$ is closer to $\frac23 n^2$. Erdos himself writes that we can get $\frac16$ "by more careful considerations" and I don't yet see what those are.

Comment: Replacing $\frac52n$ by $\frac54n - O(1)$ can make the inequality work, but this only gives us $\frac1{12}n - O(1)$ triangles.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Hi! I was able to find this paper by Bollobas and Nikiforov https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405080. The result which we want is the Corollary 2 to Theorem 1 and also it does not have $-o(1)$ term here. But The proof of Theorem 1 is a bit long.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Sorry but I am bit confused with you first comment. We know that $G(n,i_0)$ has $n-3i_0+3$ vertices. Consider triangle $\{\alpha_{i_0},\beta_{i_0},\gamma_{i_0}\}$  and set $W$ which has $n-3i_0$ vertices. We know that $|\{x\in W: (x\nsim \alpha_{i_0})\land(x\nsim \beta_{i_0})\land(x\nsim \gamma_{i_0})\}|+|\{x\in W: (x\sim \alpha_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \beta_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \gamma_{i_0})\}|=n-3i_0.$

Comment: @MishaLavrov, From any element of $\{x\in W: (x\sim \alpha_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \beta_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \gamma_{i_0})\}$ we can construct a triangle  by adding one edge unless $x$ is adjacent with all $\alpha_{i_0},\beta_{i_0},\gamma_{i_0}$.
I guess this what you meant technically but to derive the desired result? Can you elaborate it please? I mean the only confusing moment for me why it follows that there are at least $n/2$ triangles. The rest makes sense!

Comment: Partition $W$ into $W_0 \cup W_1 \cup W_2 \cup W_3$ according to the number of edges between the vertex of $W$ and the triangle. Then if there are $m$ edges between $W$ and the triangle, we have $|W_1| + 2|W_2| + 3|W_3| = m$. Meanwhile, the number of triangles created is $|W_2| + 3|W_3|$. We have $$|W_2| + 3|W_3| \ge |W_2| + 2|W_3| - |W_0| = (|W_1| + 2|W_2|+3|W_3|)-(|W_0|+|W_1|+|W_2|+|W_3|) = m - |W|.$$ So at least $m-|W|$ triangles are guaranteed to be formed.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, it makes sense now except one moment: so $m$ is the number of edges between $W$ and triangle $\{\alpha_{i_0},\beta_{i_0},\gamma_{i_0}\}$. Also we know that $v^{(i_0)}(\alpha_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\beta_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\gamma_{i_0})>\dfrac{5n}{2}-3i_0$. But the number of edges between $W$ and triangle which $m$ it should at least $|\{x\in W: (x\sim \alpha_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \beta_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \gamma_{i_0})\}|$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, But $|\{x\in W: (x\sim \alpha_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \beta_{i_0})\lor(x\sim \gamma_{i_0})\}|\leq v^{(i_0)}(\alpha_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\beta_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\gamma_{i_0})$. So my question is: I don't see how it follows that $m\geq v^{(i_0)}(\alpha_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\beta_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\gamma_{i_0})$

Comment: The number of edges $m$ is exactly equal to $v^{(i_0)}(\alpha_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\beta_{i_0})+v^{(i_0)}(\gamma_{i_0})$, because each edge is counted by exactly one of the summands. You are losing information by thinking about the neighborhood set.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thanks a lot for explanation! Now it makes sense. If at some point you will realize how to obtain $n/6$ using Erdos reasoning, then please let know. I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Can you please not spam unrelated posts with links to your question? I have already seen that question, anyway.